# Not able to retrieve the exact queried response using Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, wordpress, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm fairly new to `Swift` programming and developing ios apps. I'm building something that's going to retrieve posts and other information from a Wordpress website using `Wordpress API`. I'm using `https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` as an endpoint to get the data I need. I'm working with `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON` to pull the data and parse before I display the information in a `UICollectionView`.

I'm using parameters to query the API to get me the required data. Essentially filtering the posts at this time. The problem is that I'm always getting the default number (first ten posts) in the response. The query seems to work fine because the website was able to receive the exact query request and is responding as expected. But for whatever reason, I'm not able to see that data in the response that's received inside Xcode. It's defaulting to the first 10 posts as if there were no filters or quires applied. I have no clue what's going on. I've been trying to debug it for a couple of days without any luck. So, I'm posting here to see if anyone has any thoughts for resolving this mystery.

Following is the function I wrote for the same.

```
func getPosts() {

        Alamofire.request(baseURL, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

            if((response.result.value) != nil) {

                let postsJson = JSON(response.result.value!)
                self.posts = [SitePosts]()

                //Testing
                print(response.request as Any)
                print(response.response?.allHeaderFields)
                print("Total posts: \(postsJson.arrayValue.count)")

                do {

                    for posts in postsJson.arrayValue {
                        let  post = SitePosts()
                        let title = posts["title"]["rendered"].stringValue
                        let content = posts["content"]["rendered"].stringValue
                        let url = posts["link"].stringValue
                        let urlToImage = posts["featured_image_link"].string

                        post.content = content
                        post.title = title
                        post.url = url
                        post.imageUrl = urlToImage

                        self.posts?.append(post)

                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.postsCollectionView.reloadData()
                    }

                }


            }

        }

    }
```

Following is the response request that was sent to the API

> [AnyHashable("wpe-backend"): apache, AnyHashable("Server"): nginx,
>   AnyHashable("x-type"): default, AnyHashable("x-cacheable"): bot,
>   AnyHashable("allow"): GET, AnyHashable("x-cache"): HIT: 2,
>   AnyHashable("Cache-Control"): max-age=10800, must-revalidate,
>   AnyHashable("Content-Encoding"): gzip, AnyHashable("x-cache-group"):
>   bot, AnyHashable("x-pass-why"): ,
>   AnyHashable("access-control-expose-headers"): X-WP-Total,
>   X-WP-TotalPages, AnyHashable("x-wp-totalpages"): 8,
>   AnyHashable("Content-Type"): application/json; charset=UTF-8,
>   AnyHashable("x-content-type-options"): nosniff,
>   AnyHashable("Expires"): Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT,
>   AnyHashable("access-control-allow-headers"): Authorization,
>   Content-Type, AnyHashable("x-wp-total"): 77, AnyHashable("Date"): Fri,
>   22 Feb 2019 22:46:42 GMT, AnyHashable("Link"):
>   https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=2; rel="next",
>   AnyHashable("x-robots-tag"): noindex]

I'm using `Xcode 10.1`, `Swift 4.2`, `Alamofire (4.8.1)`, `SwiftyJSON (4.2.0)` and `Wordpress V2 API`.

I've added a breakpoint right after the Alamofire request. Attaching the screenshot of what I see.[Screenshot of the breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlWvx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something is going on with Alamofire package after archiving the project. I tried recreating the project and it worked fine until I archived the project to test on another device. So, I've switched over to urlRequest instead of using Alamofire request. Replacing Alamofire request with the below worked fine for me.

var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://mywesite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100")!)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data,response,error) in

Answer (score 0):

I guess your parameters are not being detected at server side due to different API method verb (POST, GET). Try following

```
class BaseAPIsCaller: NSObject {    
         static func post(url:String,parameters:Parameters,_ completion:@escaping (Data?,NSError?)->Void){
        let request =
            Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters,
                                                             encoding: JSONEncoding.default)

            request.responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    completion(nil,NSError(response.result.error!.localizedDescription))
                    return
                }
                guard (response.result.value as? [String: Any]) != nil else {
                    completion(nil,NSError("Didn't get json object"))
                    return
                }
                completion(response.data!,nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And then use this method anywhere like:

```
func getPosts()->Void{
    BaseAPIsCaller.post(url:"https://mywebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts", parameters: [:]) { (data:Data?, error:NSError?) in
        if let data = data {
            let json = JSON(data)
            print(json)
        }else{
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using NSError Extension

```
extension NSError{
    public convenience init(_ message:String) {
        self.init(domain: "network_error", code: -529, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:message])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work. I got the error "Didn't get json object" after trying this approach. Also, I had to change to `.post`to `.get` because I got a response saying that I'm trying to post something to the website. As I've posted, I was able to send parameters to the server because the server was responding with the response I need. For some reason, that response didn't get through Xcode and it's just showing the default behavior for the API

Comment: Can you share API with me? so I can debug?

Comment: Shmeel, I've switched to urlRequest and it worked fine. I've posted the answer as well. Thank you for taking the time to help